# Permutation with max repetition of a single element

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 16 cells that must be filled with a single number $m$ where $0<=m<=15$.
Only one number is allowed to be used twice, but that doesn't mean that it must be used twice, this means that all the cells can be different.
Examples:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 $ok$

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 0 $ok$

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 13 0 not valid, there's a number repeated 3 times

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 13 13 not valid, only one number can be repeated twice

I think all the possible outcomes are: $$16!+{16!\over{2!}}$$
Which is basically the possible outcomes when they are all different plus the possible outcomes when there's a repetition. Is it right?

Comment: The number $m$ can be different for each cell. But only one of the sixteen can be repeated twice, which means I won't be able to use all the number between 0 and 15 when there's a duplicate.

Comment: Is 1,4,3,5,3... allowed ? If not that seems correct

Comment: 1,4,3,5,3... is allowed so far, but you can't repeat any other number. Let's say you "burnt" the possibility to repeat a number.

Comment: The fact that you wrote "If not then correct" worries me about my calculation, since those numbers are allowed.

Comment: actually even if you can only "double" consecutively, I get 16!+16.16!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you say, there are $16!$ possibilities if the numbers are all different.

2) If one digit is repeated, there are 16 ways to choose the digit to be repeated, $\binom{16}{2}$ ways to choose the places
for these digits, and then $P(15,14)=15!$ ways to fill the remaining cells.

This gives a total of $16!+16\cdot15!\cdot\binom{16}{2}=16!\big(1+120\big)=16!\cdot121$ choices.

Comment: If you repeat a digit there are only 14 spaces left.

Comment: ah nevermind it works

Comment: Finally I got the same result, although using a different logic: 16!+16!/2*16(ways to choose the digit to repeat)*15(because all the other 15 numbers wil be used sooner or later, and then go into standby mode)

Comment: Is it possible from the index of the choice to tell the number? For instance, to tell what is 4000th variation?